# Is there any need of closing a database connection in django?

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-models

Is there any need of clossing a database connection in django . Or will the django automatically do it for us

Comment: If you use the Django ORM, it will use a connectionpool, and refresh (and close) the connection periodically.

Comment: Especially for some databases, like PostgreSQL, it is a bad idea to close connections, since creating a connection is rather "expensive".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to close the connection manually, because Django closes the connection automatically. [Django 3.0 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#connection-management) states:

> Django opens a connection to the database when it first makes a
> database query. It keeps this connection open and reuses it in
> subsequent requests. Django closes the connection once it exceeds the
> maximum age defined by CONN_MAX_AGE or when it isn’t usable any
> longer.
>
> In detail, Django automatically opens a connection to the database
> whenever it needs one and doesn’t have one already — either because
> this is the first connection, or because the previous connection was
> closed.
>
> At the beginning of each request, Django closes the connection if it
> has reached its maximum age. If your database terminates idle
> connections after some time, you should set CONN_MAX_AGE to a lower
> value, so that Django doesn’t attempt to use a connection that has
> been terminated by the database server. (This problem may only affect
> very low traffic sites.)
>
> At the end of each request, Django closes the connection if it has
> reached its maximum age or if it is in an unrecoverable error state.
> If any database errors have occurred while processing the requests,
> Django checks whether the connection still works, and closes it if it
> doesn’t. Thus, database errors affect at most one request; if the
> connection becomes unusable, the next request gets a fresh connection.

Comment: There is one question I have , what type of security measures I need to take to deploy a django api in a production server?

Comment: What about this note that shows up in the 4.2 docs? `If a connection is created in a long-running process, outside of Django’s request-response cycle, the connection will remain open until explicitly closed, or timeout occurs.` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#caveats). For a management command that connects to the database do we need to manually close the connection?